# How to get detailed error information when gitlab-ci fails

Tags: python, gitlab-ci

Gitlab version is 13.6.6
Gitlab-runner version is 11.2.0

my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: "python:3.7"

before_script:
  - pip install flake8

flake8:
  stage: test
  script:
    - flake8 -max-line-length=79
  tags:
    - test
```

The only information obtained from Pipelines is **script failure** and the output of failed job is **No job log**. How can I get more detailed error output？

Answer (score 0):

```
Using artifacts can help you.
image: "python:3.7"

before_script:
  - pip install flake8

flake8:
  stage: test
  script:
    - flake8 -max-line-length=79
    - cd path/to
  tags:
    - test
  artifacts:
    when: on_failure
    paths:
      - path/to/test.log
      
The log file can be downloaded via the web interface.

Note:- Using when: on_failure will ensure that test.log will only be collected if the build fails, saving disk space on successful builds.
```